# CPLEX solve one problem with many different inputs

Tags: python, parameters, linear-programming, cplex, docplex

I am solving a basic linear programming problem: `min c*x`, with an `A*x = b` constraint, using CPLEX with Python (DOCPLEX).

Then I run the above LP for 10k-100k different combinations of `b` and `c` (`A` stays fixed), in order to find the minimal solution out of those (each of them calculates a "distance" and we are looking for the "shortest" distance).

In order to achieve this, I have to "create" the problem again for each iteration, i.e. re-create the objective function and constraints every time. This setup takes 75% of my total processing time, while actual solving takes only 25%, so I'm looking to somehow speed this up. My idea is to create the problem using some sort of "template" values, and then for each (b, c) combination just pass the values and solve the problem. This sort of thing exists in other libraries such as CVXPY, but I couldn't find anything similar in CPLEX/DocPlex documentation.

Here's my "solve" method:

```py
    def _solve(self, coeffs: np.array, b: np.array) -> float:
        self._model.minimize(self._model.sum(self._model.dot(self._x, coeffs)))
        self._model.clear_constraints()
        self._model.add_constraints(
            self._model.dotf(self._x, lambda j: self._a[i][j]) == b[i]
            for i in range(self._num_colours)
        )
        sol = self._model.solve()
        return sol.get_objective_value()
```

The model, variable, and `A` are fixed and initialised once:

```py
        self._a = <GENERATE FIXED A>
        self._model = _model.Model()
        self._x = self._model.integer_var_list(self._a.shape[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

With docplex you can do incremental changes to the matrix.

See [example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooincremental.py)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

# original model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

#now 350 kids instead of 300

print()
print("now 350 kids instead of 300")    
    
mdl.get_constraint_by_name("kids").rhs=350;
mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

# no more than 4 buses 40 seats

print()
print("no more than 4 buses 40 seats")


mdl.get_var_by_name("nbBus40").ub=4
mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

#change the objective so that cost for 40 seats is 450
#and remove the limit on the number of buses 40 seats

print()
print("change the objective so that cost for 40 seats is 450")
print("and remove the limit on the number of buses 40 seats  ")  
    
mdl.get_var_by_name("nbBus40").ub=1000
mdl.set_objective("min",nbbus40*450 + nbbus30*400);
mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```